Differential equation's result under Robin boundary conditions are significantly different from those under direct given conditions
T1 = 800(*heat source temperature*);
T2 = 300(*ambient temperature*);
U = 1000(*heat transfer coefficient*);
J = 10000(*current density*);
H = 0.004(*thermoelectric material height*);
αp[x_] := 1.4831*10^-3-1.3905*10^-5 T[x]+5.3964*10^-8 (T[x])^2 -
          8.8088*10^-11*(T[x])^3+5.0618*10^-14 (T[x])^4;
κp[x_] := 1.157451*10^-1 + 4.474949*10^-2 (T[x])-
          2.597266*10^-4 (T[x])^2+5.558334*10^-7*(T[x])^3-3.676412*10^-10 (T[x])^4;
ρp[x_] := 2.728214*10^-5 - 2.254395*10^-7 (T[x])+
          7.275808*10^-10 (T[x])^2-6.25084*10^-13*(T[x])^3;
G1 = NDSolveValue[{D[κp[x]*D[T[x], x], x] + ρp[x]*J^2 - T[x]*D[αp[x], x]*J == 
                   NeumannValue[(U*(T1 - T[x]) - J*αp[x]*T[x])/(-κp[x]), x == 0] + 
                   NeumannValue[(U*(T[x] - T2) - J*αp[x]*T[x])/(-κp[x]), x == H]}, 
                   T[x], {x, 0, H}];
G2 = NDSolveValue[{D[κp[x]*D[T[x], x], x] + ρp[x]*J^2 - T[x]*D[αp[x], x]*J == 0,
                   U*(T1 - T[0]) == -κp[0]*T'[0] + J*αp[0]*T[0], 
                   U*(T[H] - T2) == -κp[H]*T'[H] + J*αp[H]*T[H]}, 
                  {T[x]}, {x}];
Plot[G1, {x, 0, H}]
Plot[G2, {x, 0, H}]



You may want to give a bit more context and include the plots in the images. What do you think is wrong and what would you expect.

That is because G1 is computed with the Finite Element method and G2 is computed with a time integration method:
In[26]:= G1[[0]]["ElementMesh"]

Out[26]= NDSolve`FEM`ElementMesh[{{0., 
   0.004}}, {NDSolve`FEM`LineElement["<" 20 ">"]}]

In[32]:= G2[[1]][[0]]["ElementMesh"]

Out[32]= None

NeumannValue has a very special meaning in the finite element world and your approach in the time integration most likely does not match that. See the documentation for more information. For example the NeumannValue ref page or FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice#1216827418 or FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOptions#62890509

Thank you very much for your kind help. Best Wishes!

Well, next time please put a bit more effort in creating a minimal working example.
Then, as pointed out by user21, you haven't set the NeumannValue correctly. The correct one should be
G1 = NDSolveValue[{D[κp[x] D[T[x], x], x] + ρp[x] J^2 - T[x] D[αp[x], x] J == 
                   NeumannValue[(* See here! -> *)-(U (T1 - T[x]) - 
                                J αp[x] T[x])(*/(-κp[x])*), x == 0] + 
                   NeumannValue[(U (T[x] - T2) - J αp[x] T[x])(*/(-κp[x])*), x == H]}, 
     T[x], {x, 0, H}];

Plot[{G1, G2}, {x, 0, H}, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}]


As to why the NeumannValue should be set in this manner, we already have a few posts about the topic, so I won't repeat the discussion here, please refer to them:
How to input Robin boundary conditions for nonstandard Laplace equation?
Laplace's equation in spherical coordinates with Neumann b.c
Using Neumann boundary conditions for the wave equation
How to set a adiabatic boundary conditions for a convection function?

Thank you very much for your kind help. Best Wishes!

@liaotianjun If my answer resolves your problem, you can give me an upvote and/or accept it: https://i.sstatic.net/63abmfBM.png
